# accesing static variables that declared inside functions

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, objdump

I want to know why we cant access variables those declared inside functions from outside the function? Its technically possible to access them  since they put in .data segment just like global/static variables. Also what is the difference between a global variable and static global variable?

I have a `C` file as following:

```
int global_n =1;
static int global_static_n=2;

int main(){
    int local_n=3;
    static int local_static_n=4;
    return 0;
}

void test(){
    global_n=9;
    global_static_n=8;
    //local_n=7;
    //local_static_n=6;
}
```

I compile and link it by the following `GCC` command:

```
gcc -Wall -m32 -nostdlib main.c -o main.o
```

I disassemble it by the following OBJDUMP commands:

```
objdump -w -j .text -D -Mi386,addr32,data32,intel main.o
objdump -w -s -j .data main.o
```

And get the following dump:

```
    Disassembly of section .text:

080480f8 <main>:
 80480f8:   55                      push   ebp
 80480f9:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
 80480fb:   83 ec 10                sub    esp,0x10
 80480fe:   c7 45 fc 03 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],0x3
 8048105:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
 804810a:   c9                      leave  
 804810b:   c3                      ret    

0804810c <test>:
 804810c:   55                      push   ebp
 804810d:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
 804810f:   c7 05 00 a0 04 08 09 00 00 00   mov    DWORD PTR ds:0x804a000,0x9
 8048119:   c7 05 04 a0 04 08 08 00 00 00   mov    DWORD PTR ds:0x804a004,0x8
 8048123:   90                      nop
 8048124:   5d                      pop    ebp
 8048125:   c3 


Contents of section .data:
```

804a000 01000000 02000000 04000000

I can see that `local_static_n` put in .data segment just like `global_static_n` and `global_n`. If i uncomment following lines i will get the errors:

```
local_n=7;
local_static_n=6;
error: ‘local_n’ undeclared (first use in this function)
error: ‘local_static_n’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Comment: Because they are scoped to the function they are declared in. That has nothing to do with the generated assembly, it's how it's defined to work in the language standard - see the [reference page on scope](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope): *"Each identifier that appears in a C program is visible (that is, may be used) only in some possibly discontiguous portion of the source code called its scope."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `static` is used in a namespace scope (i.e. outside of functions and classes), then the respective variable is visible for this translation unit only, and not for other translation units. This construct is used for avoiding unintentional name clashes of global variables defined in different translation units / libraries. This is known as "internal linkage"

If `static` is used for a variable in a function, this variable has static storage duration, but it is visible only inside the function, not outside.

Note that this "visibility" just limits the compiler when accessing the variable through its name. Of course, a function may return or otherwise expose the address of `static` variables in other ways; yet the variable itself is not visible to the compiler outside of above mentioned scopes.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know why we can't access variables those declared inside functions from outside the function? It's technically possible to access them since they put in .data segment just like global/static variables.

There is no technical problem in making it work the way you want it to. However, the guys designing the C language specifically didn't want it to work that way. The limitations are there on purpose.

Information hiding is one technique to make it easier to reason about a program by explicitly limiting the access to some data. This is one example of how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Static variables are only accessible within the scope they are declared.  However if you really need to access them:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int global_n =1;
static int global_static_n=2;

void test(int* pStatic);

int main(){
    int local_n=3;
    static int local_static_n=4;
    printf("local static %d\n",local_static_n);
    test(&local_static_n);
    printf("local static %d\n",local_static_n);
    return 0;
}

void test(int* pStatic){
    *pStatic=5;
    global_n=9;
    global_static_n=8;
    //local_n=7;
    //local_static_n=6;
}
```

However, this is not recommended.  If you want to access a static variable, you maybe should store the data in a different scope, somewhere your function and other code can access it.